# Insert break point into a javascript file

Tags: javascript, breakpoints

I would like to insert break point at a position listed in the below quote. Let's say the below quote belongs to a js file called "test.js". What I would like to do is when I run "node test.js" on the command line, it will break at the break point and then I can inspect all the variables available at the break point.

```
var a = 4;

function changeA(input) {
  var input = 6
  [INSERT BREAK POINT HERE]
  console.log(input)
};

changeA(a);
console.log(a);
```

Or is there another way to insert break point to a javascript file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hardcode a breakpoint like this:

```
debugger;
```

E.g.:

```
function changeA(input) {
  var input = 6
  debugger;
  console.log(input)
}
```

...but you have to be using a debugger for it to mean anything, such as [`node-inspector`](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector). And if you're using a debugger, you can set breakpoints through the debugger itself (rather than hardcoding them).

Here's an example of debugging a very simple NodeJS script via `node-inspector`:

Script:

```
var a = +process.argv[2];
var b = +process.argv[3];
var c = a + b;
console.log("c = " + c);
```

Command to start `node-inspector` and pass my script a couple of args:

```
node-debug temp.js 10 20
```

A browser pops up with a debugging UI and the program paused. I've set a breakpoint through the UI on the `var b = ...` line, and then stepped passed it once, so I'm sitting on the `var c = a + b;` line (which hasn't run yet):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the statement `debugger;`. You can insert that wherever you want, and if you run `node debug test.js` node will break wherever you placed the `debugger;` line.

Some of the basic commands once in debugging mode are:

- `c`: continue
- `n`: step next
- `s`: step in

You also have the ability to set breakpoints manually once in debug mode, through the following command: `setBreakpoint(line)`.

Hope this helps!

Resource: [NodeJS Debugger API](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html)

Answer (score 0):

If built-in debugger is not something you want to use, you can try [Node Inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) which allows you to debug your app using a nice GUI debug interface inside of a browser.